# Recover incomplete download in Android Open Source Project

Tags: sync, git, android, repository

I am trying to sync the following repo

> repo init -u git://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b gingerbread

and then

> repo sync

my problem is that repo sync stuck at fetching projects 99 percent. After a lot of searching, I found It want to download prebuilt package(~1.3G); however my internet connection interrupt repeatedly.

Bad news is that download resume is not supported. Good news is that I found git save all temporary file in a Packfile internally. In addition, temporary files save in projects/prebuilt.git/objects/pack/ .

is there anybody to know how I can recover incomplete download?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a "repo" consists of 176 "projects", some of them are very large (>100k of objects)
you can only resume sync if some projects are fully downloaded, but others are not.
but you cannot resume an interrupted sync of one big project. here's, a Git manual quote:

> When cloning a large repository (such
>   as KDE, Open Office, Linux kernel)
>   there is currently no way to restart
>   an interrupted clone. It may take
>   considerable time for a user on the
>   end of a small pipe to download the
>   data, and if the clone is interrupted
>   in the middle the user currently needs
>   to start over from the beginning and
>   try again. For some users this may
>   make it impossible to clone a large
>   repository.

So, if you really want to transfer these files to your machine - you'd better get access to some shell out of your network, transfer files there, and then sync your local PC and that remote shell with some restartable method, such as RSync.

Or even remotely compress all that things in one big archive, and download it to your machine with your favourite download manager.